# How to merge these two function in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the below functions in Google Sheet:

```
function DUPLICATE() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
  var rangeList = spreadsheet.getRangeList(['A15:G38', 'F8:G11', 'B9:D13']).clearContent();
  
    };

function sheetName() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getName();
  
  };
```

When I click DUPLICATE button, it triggers the first function DUPLICATE however for the second function, I need to go back to Google Script and Save in order for the cell that I assigned `=sheetName()` to change.

Is there any way that I can automate this?

Comment: Please be details what you need to do... Whats the objective? Do you want to duplicate the sheet and assign a name which is on cell?

Comment: Hi mate, sorry for the delay. Let's say my current sheet is named (A), after duplicating, the sheet's name becomes Copy of A, when I change Copy of A to B, I would like cell B3 to also change to B, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

You don't need two functions to accomplish your goal and also your current process involves a custom function which needs manual intervention to get it updated.

- In the following script you need to change two variables:

  ```
   const src_name = 'Sheet A';
   const trg_name = 'Sheet B';
  ```

and choose the sheet names of your choice. The script will duplicate `Sheet A` and rename it to `Sheet B`. Please modify these two names to your specific scenario. After you execute `DUPLICATE()`, the duplicate with the chosen name will be created, the rangelist in the target file will be cleared and you will see the name of the target sheet in cell `B3`.

---

### Solution:

```
function DUPLICATE() {
  const src_name = 'Sheet A';
  const trg_name = 'Sheet B';
  const sprd = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh_src = sprd.getSheetByName('Sheet A');
  const sh_trg =sh_src.copyTo(sprd);
  sh_trg.setName(trg_name);
  sh_trg.getRangeList(['A15:G38', 'F8:G11', 'B9:D13']).clearContent();
  sh_trg.getRange('B3').setValue(trg_name);
  sh_trg.activate();
 }
```

Comment: Hi Marios, thanks for the prompt response. Would it be possible for Google Sheet to prompt a popup asking for the user to enter the sheet's name then the entered name is changed in cell B3? If you duplicate the sheet for 2nd time, it prompts this error: 'Exception: A sheet with the name ‘Sheet B’ already exists. Please enter another name.'